# Flutter is it possible to get my app published on iOS App Store without using Cupertino widgets?

Tags: flutter

I didn't find anything regarding to my question, so Im happy about any advice.
**(There is no way to show any code which would make sense)**

I just finished my app which I want to release now in android and iOS app store.
I made the app with the `Material Widgets` but it's also of course running on my iOS device. im wondering **what exactly do I have to do now to get my app on iOS app store**.

Do I need to change everything to `Cupertino Widgets` or can I also get it published without changing everything? Is there any guide or something execept the iOS guidelines?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is a problem,we had 2 app in appstore and playstore with same codebase and design,most of them material design no problem at all,all you have to do is setup plugins and other based on ios guidelines @Marcel Dz

Comment: great, this sounds good. This is how you would exspect it if you think of a cross platform coding language. That this wouldnt be a problem

Comment: you can also show cupertino and material based on os,if you want to use the native kind of dialog and design,but it is lot of work,if you don't mind,you can use unique design to standout  @Marcel Dz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what exactly do I have to do now to get my app on iOS app store.

Relax! And publish your app without any fear. It doesn't matter if you use `Cupertino` Widgets or `Material`, the thing that matters is your app should follow Apple guidelines (which doesn't mention anything about these widgets)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was my pain too, that the apple guidelines doent tell anything about the flutter architecture and the usage of which widgets are allowed or not. So basically I can use any widget no matter of cupertino or material, thats what I wanted to know actually. Thank you!

Comment: Apple does not care about flutter architecture since all flutter applications are natively compiled. The Dart Compiler builds iOS releases via AOT, so Apple will not know the difference. They can try to decompile the app, but I don't think they would bother. As long as it works and meets the guidelines it's enough.

Comment: That sounds good. Yes I was wondering about that. What Ive heard and read so far I always said to myself: There shouldnt be any differnce since the idea of flutter was to make it cross compatible, so there shouldnt be a difference in using either Material or Cuptertino. That means that Widgets Material or Cupertino are only visual differences right? I read that flutter devs just build those elements like they look native am I right?